# Trouble with minimal java agent

Tags: java, agent

I can't seem to get a simple agent to work and it's frustrating me quite a bit...

Class upon which agent will act:

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello from main");
    }
}
```

Agent class:

```
package instrumentation;

public class Agent {
    public static void premain(String args, 
            Instrumentation inst) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Hello from agent");
    }
}
```

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Premain-Class: instrumentation.Agent
```

JVM argument passed:

```
-javaagent:C:\path\to\agent.jar
```

The only output I get is:

```
Hello from main
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Funny enough, the position at which you place your `javaagent` argument matters; It must come before the `jar` argument.

So try this:

```sh
java -javaagent:agent.jar -jar agent.jar
```

Assuming your java agent is packaged along with your source, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your input, although I'm running it in IntelliJ, providing `-javaagent:C:\path\to\agent.jar` as my program argument and don't want to execute the program from cmd line. Not sure as well why I'd pass the jar again as a jar arg?